# Windows account cannot access TIBCO Spotfire Server

Tags: spotfire

I installed Spotfire Web Player 4.5.0 on the same server as IIS 8, both are on Windows Server 2012.  I set up to use Single Sign-On Using Delegation with Kerberos Login System.  The Spotfire server is set up to use Kerberos Login System.  I’m able to connect to the Spotfire Web Player from the browser and then the Web Player automatically logs onto the Spotfire Server.  This only works when I’m using a browser from inside the server where the Web Player and IIS are installed.  From outside of that server, I get “The Windows account for  cannot access TIBCO Spotfire Server.  Could not authenticate user ”.  It seems like from within the server, the Web Player is able to pass my credential to the Spotfire server but coming from outside it can’t?  Please advise, thank you in advance.

Note:  I followed the setup & configuration as provided by the Spotfire Web Player installation guide.  The only one thing that I didn’t do exactly as the instruction is uncheck the ‘Enable Kernel-mode authentication’ checkbox in the Spotfire web application’s Windows Authentication settings.  If I uncheck the box, then I will be prompted for credential every time I go to the Spotfire web app.

Comment: Does the spotfire service account user have admin permissions inside the Spotfire Administration Manager?

Comment: Yes it does.  The Web Player uses the application pool that uses a custom user account that has admin privilege on the Spotfire Server.  As mentioned above, it works when I use the browser in the server that has the Web Player & IIS; in the Spotfire Server log, it logged my user name.  When I use a browser from outside of that serve, the logs show ‘UNKNOWN’.  It seems like the Web Player can pass my credential when I’m inside that server but not when I’m outside.

Comment: Do you have to log on to the Windows box or is it an open system? Is it a domain box using AD?

Comment: It's a domain box and I have to logon using my AD username & password.

Comment: Updated:  The configuration of the Spotfire web site hosted on IIS has been updated as follow: (1)  Windows Authentication --> Advanced Settings --> Extended Protection is set to 'Accept' instead of 'Off' (2) Windows Authentication --> Providers --> make sure 'Negotiate' is on top of the Enabled Providers list.  This only works for people who are in this server's Administrators group, they can access the Web Player's library page from a browser outside of the server and view all reports.  People not in the Administrator group can only see the library page but won't be able to view any reports.

Comment: There might be some kind group policy, permission and/or configurations issues that I still have to figure out...

Comment: People who's not in the Administrator group weren't able to access the report and the logs have "access denied.." error.  As it turns out, there's a Temp folder within the Web Player folder, the Administrator group was given permission that allow the group to modify; the Everyone group needs that permission as well.